# Solr: Get X results in a range above and below a defined number / timestamp

Tags: solr

If I have a numeric field, I can get results sorted ascending or descending on that field.

I want to be able to get X results above and below a certain number within that field.

This is actually for a timestamp - I want to get a results that surround a certain time (before and after), but I don't know the frequency of the documents. I want the 5 results that come before this time and 5 results that come after.

The only way I can think of doing this is two requests, for a range from the specified time to * and one from 0 to the specified time, then combining them in the application.

Is there any other way?

Comment: What's the reason for not making two separate queries? Streaming Expressions could work with two [Stream Sources](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/stream-sources.html#stream-sources) and a [Merge operator](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/stream-decorators.html#merge)

Comment: Try group query. Example given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53552809/2536745

Comment: Your group query will be, group.query=ts_field:[0 TO your_ts]&group.query=ts_field:[your_ts TO *]